# What's the generic term for meaningless interactivity?

Tags: interaction-design, terminology, click

We talk about *visual noise* to refer to profuse, redundant or meaningless elements towards the purpose of the design.

What's the name when it comes to "*noise*" in interactivity?

- The bottom image has a redundant click: displaying a two-line image caption below a photo.

[image: caption]

---

Searching the internet for "click noise" or "interactivity noise" only gives sound effect answers...

Comment: I would call it a "superfluous interaction".

Comment: That's NOT a redundant click. Captions provide valuable information to users with low or no vision. The caption is included in this page in a way that screen readers can pick up and offer the user the option to read it or skip it. To prevent having a two-tiered site (one for users with accessibility need and another for those without) this designer/developer has come up with a solution that serves both. **The ableist habit of viewing accessibility concessions as superfluous features needs to stop.** In any case, I never talk about any kind of "noise" but I do talk about cognitive load.

Comment: And one might argue that forcing users to constantly expand information panels to retrieve small amounts of information creates an obstacle for users with mobility impairments.

Comment: @AndrewMartin - *Captions provide valuable information to users with low or no vision.* - Ok, what's the point of hiding it and making it visible after a click? Why not simply leave it visible?

Comment: @Izquierdo You might argue that but the counter-argument would be that the caption is supplementary to the main content so the user should have the option to ignore it. In the case of motor impairments, it would fall to individual cases as to whether the extra scroll generated by leaving the caption open balanced against the extra click when leaving it closed. Not to mention the possibility of using the tab index functionality to move through the various parts of the page without requiring too much muscular effort or control.

Comment: @Danielillo Just as you can see it but have the option of ignoring it, visually impaired users should be able to acknowledge its existence without having it interrupt their experience of the main content if they do not want it to. From my original comment: "The caption is included in this page in a way that screen readers can pick up and offer the user the option to read it or skip it."

Comment: @AndrewMartin Screen readers don't need an accordion's expand/collapse functionality to make content optionally skippable, and I would not recommend that engineers code pages that way.

Comment: @Izquierdo No, you're right; they don't need an accordion but they do need the anchor that is being used to operate the accordion here. It also allows them to skip the container entirely if they wish. Also, with an accordion action like this, able-bodied users can recognise the caption and click to read it if they wish, vision-impaired users can recognise the caption and click to read it if they wish, users with cognitive impairments can also recognise the caption and leave it hidden if they feel it will disrupt their ability to digest the main content.

Comment: @AndrewMartin This collapse/expand label needs a click. Wouldn't it be better to display the caption by simply hovering over the image? That's what I mean by unnecessary interaction.

Comment: @Danielillo A hover function would not work for users with screen-readers and may cause an unnecessary distraction for users with cognitive impairments. The positive click here solves all of those problems.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### This is sometimes referred to as 'excise'.

Alan Cooper in the classic software guide **About Face** refers to the larger term *Excise* whenever you have extra decorations, extra interactions, and the like:

This could be classified as **visual excise:** (page 226)

> Visual excise is the work that a user has to do to decode visual information, such as
> finding a single item in a list, figuring out where to begin reading on a screen, or
> determining which elements on it are clickable and which are merely decoration.

A broader summary of problems with excise in the book:

> The problem with excise tasks is that the effort we expend in doing them doesn’t go
> directly towards accomplishing our goals. Where we can eliminate the need for
> excise tasks, we make people more effective and productive and improve the usability of a product, ultimately creating a better user experience. As an interaction
> designer, you should become sensitive to the presence of excise and take steps to
> eradicate it with the same enthusiasm a doctor would apply to curing an infection.
> The existence of excise in user interfaces is a primary cause of user dissatisfaction
> with software-enabled products. It behooves every designer and product manager
> to be on the lookout for interaction excise in all its

Comment: Cool, I didn't know this, but this answer raises a lot of other questions for me. Anyway, excise refers to visual elements, not to interaction or clicks, which is what I mean in the question. "Clicks Excise"? By the way there isn't a literal Spanish translation, excise is related to "tax". I keep investigating.

Comment: 'tax' is a perfect root for this. If you read the book, he also refers to interactions, unnecessary processes, and anything that 'gets in the way' of a user accomplishing a goal.

Comment: *Excise task* is closer. Maybe I don't understand it very well because of the translation or because I can't find the right word in Spanish. I will ask the question in SpanishSE. Very good info anyway.

Comment: @Danielillo Maybe there is no direct Spanish word but it is like tax: The extra effort you have to "pay" on top of the minimal effort it would cost. Just like with products that you would gladly pay for if it had the normal price, but with the excise tax you know that the price is artificially kept high. (Normally governments that charges extra on products that involve health problems and addictions, like cigarettes.)

Comment: Yes, I'm getting it (or I still in process   ) I have an answer similar than your comment in [SpanishSE](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/39980/19361). I think it's a *lost in translation* issue. We can say "Tarea impuesta" for excise task but "Visual impuesto" or "impuesto visual" sounds weird, it should be "imposición visual" although it deviates slightly from the meaning of @MikeM 's answer. Impuesto Visual is a real tax.

Answer (score 2):

The British slang term **Faff** fits well.

From https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/faff we have...

> (Britain, slang) An overcomplicated task, especially one perceived as a waste of time.

I'd suggest "faffUX" but you might get in trouble saying it out loud ;)

Comment: In OP’s case, it’s not an overcomplicated task. Task is simple - click the button to expand. But this button should not be required and that info should be visible as default. OP is asking for a term to denote that should-not-be-required interaction which is thrusted on user.

Comment: Perhaps, but Faff is a lot more fun.  It's a slang approach to answering the question as opposed to being academic about it.  Not all solutions or answers need to be academic.